# Почему разные классы указывают на один и тот же список?

Tags: python, память, указатели

Здравствуйте!

Только что обнаружил странное и нехорошее поведение python (ver. 2.7.):

```
>>> class A(object):
    l = []
    i = 1

>>> a1 = A()
>>> b1 = A()

>>> print a1.l
    []
>>> print a1.i
    1

>>> print b1.l
    []
>>> print b1.i
    1

>>> a1.l.append('A1')
>>> a1.i = 2
>>> b1.l.append('B1')
>>> b1.i = 3

>>> print a1.l
    ['A1', 'B1']
>>> print a1.i
    2

>>> print b1.l
    ['A1', 'B1']
>>> print b1.i
    3

>>> del a1
>>> del b1

>>> a2 = A()
>>> b2 = A()

>>> print a2.l
    ['A1', 'B1']
>>> print a2.i
    1

>>> print b2.l
     ['A1', 'B1']
>>> print b2.i
    1
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, причину такого поведения. Почему четыре разных класса вдруг показывают на один список? Даже после удаления первых двух.

Кстати, если добавить в `class A` деструктор с командой '`del self.l`', будет ошибка:

```
Exception AttributeError: 'l' in <bound method A.__del__ of <__main__.A object at 0x105907ed0>> ignored
```

Что это значит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так. Кажется, разобрался.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     l = []
...     i = 1
>>> print A
    <class '__main__.A'>
>>> print A.l
    []
```

Похоже, все, что внутри A, создается единожды при создании самого класса. Экземпляры же получают ссылки на сложные объекты (списки, функции и т. д.), а простые (числа) генерируют заново. Здорово :)

Comment: Почти так. Только ссылки получают на все объекты. Просто числа неизменяемы.

Comment: Если в конструкторе инициализируете - тогда все будет замечательно.

А в самом классе - думайте об этом как о межклассовых переменных.

То же самое поведение и в функциях в значениях по умолчанию:

    def f(a = 0, b = []):
        a += 1
        b.append(1)

При вызове `f()`, `a` - всегда будет равно 1 (0 + 1 = 1), а `b` - будет постоянно увеличиваться

Answer (score 1):

Надо:

```
>>> class A(object):
    l = None
    i = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.l = []
```

Тогда переменной будет присваиваться новый адрес в памяти при инициализации каждого нового экземпляра этого класса, иначе он присвоится один раз при объявлении класса (как в вашем примере)